# How to Achieve this effect in Css display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am pretty confused with this effect which is pretty Awesome for Image Grid System.What would be the Css code to Achieve this effec[image]t

My Try...

```
.container{
 display:flex;
   justify-content: center; 
align-items: center; 
     flex-wrap:wrap ;

}
```

Unfortunately this is not working of dynamically upadated Image Like Above..

Comment: No I want Custom Grid Layout Is it Hard to make it

Comment: maybe give a try to flex-flow:column; also and see what happens ... If you set a fiddle, a codepen or a snippet , so we can see your html and also where it goes wrong.Then we might advise and help

Comment: Just Wait I will  Do a CodePen

Comment: `http://codepen.io/githubitsme/pen/NbarmP/` Take Look at this code Pen